# Why does clang produce a much faster code than gcc for this simple function involving exponentiation?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, optimization, clang

The following code compiled with `clang` runs almost 60 times faster than the one compiled with`gcc` with identical compiler flags (either `-O2` or `-O3`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>

long double func(int num)
{
    long double i=0;
    long double k=0.7;

    for(int t=1; t<num; t++){
      for(int n=1; n<16; n++){
        i += pow(k,n);
      }
    }
    return i;
}


int main()
{
   volatile auto num = 3000000; // avoid constant folding

   std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
   start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

   auto i = func(num);

   end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end-start;
   std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_digits10);
   std::cout << "Result " << i << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Elapsed time is " << elapsed.count() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I have tested this with three `gcc` versions `4.8.4/4.9.2/5.2.1` and two `clang` versions `3.5.1/3.6.1` and here are the timings on my machine (for `gcc 5.2.1` and `clang 3.6.1`):

**Timing `-O3`:**

```
gcc:    2.41888s
clang:  0.0396217s
```

**Timing `-O2`:**

```
gcc:    2.41024s
clang:  0.0395114s
```

**Timing `-O1`:**

```
gcc:    2.41766s
clang:  2.43113s
```

So it seems that `gcc` does not optimize this function at all even at higher optimization levels. The assembly output of `clang` is almost around 100 lines longer than `gcc` and I don't think it is necessary to post it here, all I can say is that in `gcc` assembly output there is a call to `pow` which does not appear in `clang` assembly, presumably because `clang` optimizes it to a bunch of intrinsic calls.

Since the results are identical (i.e. `i = 6966764.74717416727754`), the question is:

1. Why can `gcc` not optimize this function when `clang` can?
2. Change the value of `k` to `1.0` and `gcc` becomes as fast, is there a floating point arithmetic issue that `gcc` cannot by-pass?

I did try `static_cast`ing and turned on the warnings to see if there was any issue with implicit conversions, but not really.

**Update:** For completeness here are the results for `-Ofast`

```
gcc:    0.00262204s
clang:  0.0013267s
```

The point is that `gcc` does not optimize the code at `O2/O3`.

Comment: Did you print out the assembly language, generated by both compilers?

Comment: Is clang using the same standard library implementation as gcc here? One of them may have a faster / less accurate pow implementation or something. (Just a guess)

Comment: How identical are the results? `6.96676e+06` doesn't show enough precision to be sure. For a speedup like this, I would guess Clang is on settings that allow things like swapping the loop order, which doesn't quite produce the same results.

Comment: I get similar results with MSVS 2015 so there has to be something gcc is not doing in its optimizations that clang and MSVS are.

Comment: The 'dichotomy' of your question? What exactly is that supposed to mean?

Comment: why do you include `math.h` instead of `cmath`?

Comment: is there any value in this question? in a future release gcc will start being able to perform this optimization and there will be no reason to come back to this question. Bad fit for SO imo.

Comment: Have you checked that both versions obtain the correct result (down to the precision expected?)

Comment: @jepio There is clearly a value in both the question and current top answer. Not only I learned about compile time optimization of pow (maybe common knowledge), but this may very well be a defect inside gcc. I don't see why this optimization should be enabled only with -Ofast.

Comment: The relevant gcc flag is `-fno-math-errno`. Gcc tries to be conservative and believes that non-pure calls are a sign that unrolling is unlikely to help much. Obviously this is the wrong choice here, but I am not sure how easy it would be to improve the heuristic. Feel free to file a report on gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it is interesting that when `n < 4` gcc does seem to do a similar optimization as clang, why does it stop applying it after `4`?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't check, but obviously with unrolling, the more iterations of the loop, the more code will grow if you unroll completely, so you have to be more conservative when unrolling many iterations than just a few.

Comment: @MarcGlisse ok, I see that now, thank you.

Comment: It is not difficult to find code segments or functions that one compiler or set of options does better than another.  If compilers were perfect there would be no future versions other than to add new languages.  Of course then we would have to get into the definition of perfect.  If differently branded compilers produced identical results, one might argue for a lawsuit, stolen IP.  Not necessarily in this case sure as they are both open source.

Comment: basically there is absolutely no reason to expect every compiler to find every optimization, nor is there any reason to expect any two compilers to produce the same result.  Take any decent sized project and it is easy to find an optimization the compiler missed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From this [godbolt session](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVSIOwAsA6BkpC8aeZFCB3dGHTkyUQQHMkcdDABGUZADMYkABThsSMDCIBKMgG8ySE0jFhJ0uQqQgAvAAYA3MdPnLM%2BcgDWjpgHYXVxNFdFx1ME1sOwBGJyRsFG0ieOwAajTdI1NTUPCNLVj4sBQYgDZijKzgnNskNLskAAd0AHdVbwAaMF0XWqQAXxqhnPxsGFwwWxchsjmCunBVfSMAN3QoehAbAhhsdC0dJEaAZgdzi76TXf26xuU1ZN659gGgAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang37x%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-pedantic%20-O3%20-fverbose-asm%22%7D%5D%7D) clang is able to perform all the `pow` calculations at compile time. It knows at compile time what the values of `k` and `n` are and it just constant folds the calculation:

```
.LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4604480259023595110     # double 0.69999999999999996
.LCPI0_1:
    .quad   4602498675187552091     # double 0.48999999999999994
.LCPI0_2:
    .quad   4599850558606658239     # double 0.34299999999999992
.LCPI0_3:
    .quad   4597818534454788671     # double 0.24009999999999995
.LCPI0_4:
    .quad   4595223380205512696     # double 0.16806999999999994
.LCPI0_5:
    .quad   4593141924544133109     # double 0.11764899999999996
.LCPI0_6:
    .quad   4590598673379842654     # double 0.082354299999999963
.LCPI0_7:
    .quad   4588468774839143248     # double 0.057648009999999972
.LCPI0_8:
    .quad   4585976388698138603     # double 0.040353606999999979
.LCPI0_9:
    .quad   4583799016135705775     # double 0.028247524899999984
.LCPI0_10:
    .quad   4581356477717521223     # double 0.019773267429999988
.LCPI0_11:
    .quad   4579132580613789641     # double 0.01384128720099999
.LCPI0_12:
    .quad   4576738892963968780     # double 0.0096889010406999918
.LCPI0_13:
    .quad   4574469401809764420     # double 0.0067822307284899942
.LCPI0_14:
    .quad   4572123587912939977     # double 0.0047475615099429958
```

and it unrolls the inner loop:

```
.LBB0_2:                                # %.preheader
    faddl   .LCPI0_0(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_1(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_2(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_3(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_4(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_5(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_6(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_7(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_8(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_9(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_10(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_11(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_12(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_13(%rip)
    faddl   .LCPI0_14(%rip)
```

Note, that it is using a builtin function(*[gcc documents theirs here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)*) to calculate `pow` at compile time and if we use [-fno-builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) it no longer performs this optimization.

If you change `k` to `1.0` then [gcc is able to perform](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVSIOwAsA6BkpC8aeZFCB3dGHTkyUQQHMkcdDABGUZADMYkABThsSMDCIBKMgG8ySE0jFhJ0uQqQgAvAAYA3MdPnLM%2BcgDWdgIxMzmSuJorouOpgmtj%2BTkjYKNpEcdgA1Km6RqamYREaWrFaKH4AbHFg6Zkh2bZIqXZIAA7oAO6q3gA0YLouNUgAvtWD2fjYMLhgti6DwWT5dOCq%2BkYAbuhQ9CA2BDDY6Fo6SA0AzA5n570mO3u1DcpqST3B7P1AA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-pedantic%20-O3%20-fverbose-asm%20%22%7D%5D%7D) the same optimization:

```
.L3:
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    addl    $1, %eax    #, t
    cmpl    %eax, %edi  # t, num
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    fadd    %st, %st(1) #,
    jne .L3 #,
```

Although it is a simpler case.

If you change the condition for the inner loop to `n < 4` then [gcc seems willing to optimize](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVSIOwAsA6BkpC8aeZFCB3dGHTkyUQQHMkcdDABGUZADMYkABThsSMDCIBKMgG8ySE0jFhJ0uQqQgAvAAYA3MdPnLM%2BcgDWjpgHYXVxNFdFx1ME1sOwBGJyRsFG0ieOwAajTdI1NTUPDMEAAvBAB9TTBY%2BLAUABYqjKzgnNskNLskAAd0AHdVbwAaMF0XZqQAXyaJnPxsGFwwWxcJshWNJDpwVX0jADd0KHoQGwIYbHQtHSR2gGYHO%2FuRkxOzlvblNWThlfYxoAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-pedantic%20-O3%20-fverbose-asm%20%22%7D%5D%7D) when `k = 0.7`. As indicated in the comments to the question, if the compiler does not believe unrolling will help then it will likely be conservative in how much unrolling it will do since there is a code size trade off.

As indicated in the comments I am using a modified version of the OP's code in the godbolt examples but it does not change the underlying conclusion.

Note as indicated in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358488/why-does-clang-produce-a-much-faster-code-than-gcc-for-this-simple-function-invo#comment54551265_33358488) if we use [-fno-math-errno](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), which stops `errno` from being set, gcc does apply [a similar optimization](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVSIOwAsA6BkpC8aeZFCB3dGHTkyUQQHMkcdDABGUZADMYkABThsSMDCIBKMgG8ySE0jFhJ0uQqQgAvAAYA3MdPnLM%2BcgDWjpgHYXVxNFdFx1ME1sOwBGJyRsFG0ieOwAajTdI1NTUPCNLVj4sBQYgDZijKzgnNskNLskAAd0AHdVbwAaMF0XWqQAXxqhnPxsGFwwWxchsjmCunBVfSMAN3QoehAbAhhsdC0dJEaAZgdzi76TXf26xuU1ZN659gGgAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-pedantic%20-O3%20-fverbose-asm%20-fno-math-errno%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: Also note that clang's `main` never calls `func`, because it realizes it has no side effects.  It just stores/reloads 3000000 to/from the stack, clears eax, and returns.  gcc does the same with `-fast-math`, and also optimizes `func` more.  godbolt doesn't put a label in front of the iostream constructor that sits after `main`, so it looks like `main` has more code than it actually does.

Comment: why doesn't it use SSE2?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes indeed, if we add a `std::cout << i ;` to `main` then it will inline the function into `main`, it does not change the overall conclusion.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: `long double` is 80bit in the SysV ABI.  x87 is the fastest way to do floats wider than 64bit.  (so-called "double double" is 128bit, with twice the number of mantissa bits, but the exponent from only one double.  In any case, `long double` isn't double double in x86-64 or x86, with the standard ABI.)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: **oops**, I didn't notice the difference between your modified source on godbolt which doesn't use the result, while the OP's code does.  So that 39ms is the time it's taking to actually do the computation.  If the OP's `main` was really optimized away to `return 0`, it would take more like 0.001s (like GNU /bin/true on my system).  So yes, this does explain the OP's run time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Shafik Yaghmour's answer, I'd like to point out that the reason your use of `volatile` on the variable `num` appears to have no effect is that `num` is read before `func` is even called. The read can't be optimized away, but the function call can still be optimized away. If you declared the parameter of `func` to be a reference to `volatile`, ie. `long double func(volatile int& num)`, this would prevent the compiler from optimizing away the entire call to `func`.